# jss start:connected mode error 'scjss-verify-setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

I did a NPM install and it broke my jss start:connected mode.
I type jss start:connected and then it errors out. In the Package.json file it errors out on

```
"start:connected": "scjss-verify-setup && npm-run-all --serial bootstrap:connected --parallel theme-watch start:angular start:watch-components",
```

The error that shows up
**'scjss-verify-setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
I have attached a pic below that tells what versions I have.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

I suspect it has something to do with the version of JSS that you are using, or perhaps has to do with your operating system or line endings.

I found this discussion on GitHub that mentions the exact error you are experiencing:

https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/issues/29

The implication of the above is that you may need to update your version of JSS.

#### Solution 2:

Verify that `scjss-verify-setup` is defined *somewhere*.

For example, the [main JSS repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/59f6cbb2a6e1ab20a0ea817fcae71a0cc01a6c40/packages/sitecore-jss-dev-tools/package.json), defines the following in `jss/packages/sitecore-jss-dev-tools/package.json`:

```
  "bin": {
    "scjss-verify-setup": "./dist/cjs/bin/verify-setup.js"
  },
```

Verify that the command is defined and that the file it is referencing exists. The safest bet would be to do a "find all" on your entire directory.

#### Solution 3:

Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

#### Additional Questions:

- Which version of JSS are you using?
- Which version of the JSS-CLI are you using?
- Which OS are you using?

Comment: The JSS verion i am using is 13.0.5  and windows 10. The link you provided, that guys is using a mac.  Sitecore 9.3

Comment: @MrSumo answer has been updated.